# Microcontroller as a slave

Tags: microcontroller, ethercat

I want to set up an EtherCAT Network, First I have installed IgH EtherCAT Master in my PC (Ubuntu 14.04) and RTAI 4.1 as RTOS

Can I use microcontroller as a slave without any additional devices provided by Backoff or other suppliers like (FPGA, ASIC)

Comment: Define 'slave'   ?

Comment: In EtherCAT we have two types of devices
A master and many devices to process data on the fly
I need the help from someone who know EtherCAT

Comment: So you want a microcontroller to run EtherCAT as a slave?  Because that is not clear in your question.  So what will the slave do?  PC master - EtherCAT - Slave.

Comment: I want to calculate the cycle time using wireshark, PC as a master and the microcontroller as a slave.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Simple Open EtherCAT Slave or SOES](http://openethercatsociety.github.io/doc/soes/index.html) 
on a microcontroller. SOES supports the Distributed Clock mode.

To estimate the effort of installing the SOES on a microcontroller,
have a look at https://bitbucket.org/utwente_bss/soes_arm/wiki/Home .
The slave version referred to in the wiki is not the latest but gives you enough hints.

Another option is [light ethercat slave](http://sourceforge.net/p/ecslave/wiki/Howto/). This one is the most hardware independent.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Can you please summarize at a very high level the content in the links?